# How to integrate Facebook in iOS 6 using SLRequest?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6

I've been looking around trying to figure out how to integrate Facebook in iOS6 using SLRequests. I was able to do it after some research.
Here's some code snippet that show how it's done.

```
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    __block ACAccount *facebookAccount = nil;

    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    // Specify App ID and permissions
    NSDictionary *options = @{
    ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"012345678912345",
    ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
    ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
    };

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
        options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) 
        {
            if (granted)
            {
                NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

                facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
             }
             else
             {
              // Handle Failure
             }
         }];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": @"My first iOS 6 Facebook posting "};

    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest 
                              requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST 
                              URL:feedURL 
                              parameters:parameters];

    feedRequest.account = facebookAccount;

    [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, 
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         // Handle response
     }];
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't requestAccessToAccountsWithType: async? How are you able to get facebookAccount before feedRequest is used?

Answer (score 21):

I have a write up on how to use SLRequest.

```
-(IBAction)postMessage:(id)sender
{
    // Create the URL to the end point
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    NSString *link = @"http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233";
    NSString *message = @"Testing Social Framework";
    NSString *picture = @"http://www.stuarticus.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/SDKsmall.png";
    NSString *name = @"Social Framework";
    NSString *caption = @"Reference Documentation";
    NSString *description = @"The Social framework lets you integrate your app with supported social networking services. On iOS and OS X, this framework provides a template for creating HTTP requests. On iOS only, the Social framework provides a generalized interface for posting requests on behalf of the user.";

    NSDictionary *postDict = @{
    @"link": link,
    @"message" : message,
    @"picture" : picture,
    @"name" : name,
    @"caption" : caption,
    @"description" : description
    };

    SLRequest *postToMyWall = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:postURL parameters:postDict];

    FacebookAccountManager* sharedManager = [FacebookAccountManager sharedAccount];
    [postToMyWall setAccount:sharedManager.facebookAccount];

    [postToMyWall performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error) {
            // If there is an error we populate the error string with error
            _errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [error localizedDescription]];

            // We then perform the UI update on the main thread. All UI updates must be completed on the main thread.
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateErrorString) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Post successful");
            NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
            NSLog(@"Response Data: %@", dataString);
        }
     }];
}
```

Full post and app download available here: https://github.com/stuarticus/SocialFrameworkReference