# Invite facebook friends in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I want to integrate Facebook in my app. The functionality like this the user will login in to Facebook, then fetch the all friends & send the friend request for the app. I uses IOS6.

So, is there any solution for this using Social framework?

**How can i do this?**

I get code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017105/fetch-facebook-friend-list-using-slrequest-in-ios-6-0/16412894#16412894)

But getting error for account.

Answer (score 2):

This:[Facebook SDK for iOS and the iOS 6 Facebook Integration](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/25/facebook-sdk-for-ios-and-the-ios-6-facebook-integration/)

and this:[How to easily integrate your iOS App with Facebook](http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/05/how-to-easily-integrate-your-ios-app-with-facebook/)

UPDATE: **App Request**

**You can easily send the app request very easily by Using Facebook SDK
For Making App Request Please Make sure Following steps**

1)*Make sure you have added the latest Facebook SDK in Your Application Folder*

**if not,you may download from this link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk**

**Now you just need to Add FBConnect Folder in your Project Folder.**

2)*Then Make sure you have Registered your iphone App as "App on Facebook" Type Select how your app integrates with Facebook under Basic App Settings.*

**if not,you can do that here https://developers.facebook.com/apps/**

```
NSString *friendId=@"FacebookId Of Your Friends";

NSLog(@"%@",friendId);

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hi please add me as a friend.",  @"message",
                                   friendId, @"to",
                                   nil];
 [appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params  andDelegate:self];
```

**Also, don't forget to adopt the FBdialogDelegate protocol first in your ViewController Class.**

UPDATE2: **Friend Request**

**Create a NSMutableDictionary to make a "appRequest" with their corresponding parameters but indicate that the type of dialogue is a "friends". It's a strange solution but it works.**

```
Facebook *face = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FBSession.activeSession.appID andDelegate:nil];
face.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;
face.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;
if ([face isSessionValid]){
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"My Title", @"title",
                                   @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                                   userId, @"id",
                                   nil];
    [face dialog:@"friends"
       andParams:[params mutableCopy]
     andDelegate:nil];
}
```

***Hope this helps you out. If so, please feel free to accept the answer.***

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! But how can i send friend request?

Comment: Send friend request to another facebook user from your iOS App, right ?

Comment: Yes, i want send request to other facebook user.

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Comment: But i think, it is for ios5 not for ios6.

Comment: You are wrong. - https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: Thare is no FBConnect folder in downloaded SDk.

Comment: Ignore the first UPDATE and check out UPDATE2 in my answer above. It is exactly what you're looking for about sending a friend request. If you have no further questions, please feel free to accept this answer by clicking the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.

Comment: But where is the facebook class file?

Comment: I think question is basically invite a friend using ios 6 slrequest class but all answers are using facebook sdk.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this over here :

[send-requests-using-ios-sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/)

and
[invites and requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/)

Hope it helps you.