# Invite Facebook friend using SLRequest class

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios6

I want to invite user's friend using SLRequest class of ios 6.But I am not getting what will be the exact url and parameters of in graph api?
I am using same code as described in [Fetch Facebook friend list using SLRequest in ios 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017105/fetch-facebook-friend-list-using-slrequest-in-ios-6-0) to fetch friend list. Now I want to integrate the invite friend functionality.

I don't want to use facebook sdk as I already have code using social kit of ios 6.

Thanks