# SLComposeViewController Facebook posts as iOS instead of Facebook Application Identifier

Tags: ios, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'm currently working on a prototype for adding Facebook social features for future iOS games. One of the features I've been working on involves using the new native Facebook Composer to post to a link to the game, and then tracking the post and giving the player coins for every person who likes the post. After the post, I get their feed and look for a post with a matching application ID. I've already got that part working correctly if I don't use the new native Facebook Composer (either old style dialogs, or just a direct post with no dialog).

The problem I'm encountering is when using the new SLComposeViewController, the post will appear to come from the application "iOS" id "213546525407071" rather than the id for my application.

Is there a way to change the attributed application so that it uses my application ID instead of iOS?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605241/730701).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how `SLComposeViewController` works. If you want your own app designated, you have to design your own UI and use `FBRequestConnection` from the Facebook SDK as discussed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/).