# SLComposeViewController bind to app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, fbconnect, slcomposeviewcontroller

If I use `SLComposeViewController` factory initializer method `composeViewControllerForServiceType:` and initialize it with Facebook service type, when posting to the Facebook wall, the post does not contain any info on the app it was used to post from (it now says "via iOS", instead of "via ApplicationName"). When I was using FBConnect and would specify AppID, it would always fetch the application info display it within the post.

Is it possible to recreate this behavior with standard `SLComposeViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this at the moment with SLComposeViewController.
You have to use the Facebook SDK to have your apps name in the "via area".

see
[SLComposeViewController Facebook posts as iOS instead of Facebook Application Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094661/slcomposeviewcontroller-facebook-posts-as-ios-instead-of-facebook-application-id)

Comment: As was pointed out in a comment on my answer for this here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605241/662605) The DIGG app does this ! It says via DIGG...