# UIActivityViewController change shared via iOS

Tags: ios, uikit, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have simple sharing features in my app by using iOS 6 UIActivityView controller.

When sharing in Facebook or Twitter there is a "shared via iOS"

the code is:

```
NSString *textToShare = @"Test string to share";

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:textToShare] applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

is there any way to change "Shared via iOS" to my app name or anything else?

[image: shareviaios]

Thanks,
Bill.

Comment: look at this issue , it's the same 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547616/sharing-with-ios-6-0-native-facebook-integration-posted-via-my-app-name

Comment: the last post says when released it will happen automatically... Thanks for pointing me in this...

Comment: Anyone verified this? Also does this mean it would appear as expected when developing an app which already exists in the app store (working on an update)

Comment: Hi Daniel, The app is now released and I can confirm that still says shared via iOS. Nothing changed.

Comment: @BillKast look at this answer on that same question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605241/801913

Answer (score 0):

> **iOS 6 Share Sheet**
>
> The iOS 6 share sheet is a feature of Apple's Facebook integration.
>
> **Disadvantages**
>
> Posts from the share sheet are attributed to iOS by default; **contact Facebook to correctly configure attribution for your app**

[Sharing and Distribution on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/)