# change "shared via iOS" to "shared via <AppName>

Tags: ios, facebook, sharing, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am using a SLComposeViewController to post to facebook. However all of these posts have a "shared via iOS" tag instead of "shared via my app name". Any idea how to fix this?
[The stack overflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547616/sharing-with-ios-6-0-native-facebook-integration-posted-via-my-app-name/12605241#12605241) states this can be done by contacting developer relations. Is this really the easiest way and how would I even do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a manual process and need to contact Facebook to do it (or the Facebook app needs to be published on the Facebook App store) according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605241/801913

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook's share dialog's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/) gives a somewhat definitive answer here. You do have to contact Facebook to change the default "shared via iOS". I'm not sure what the best way to contact facebook but luckily the documentation describes some alternatives to change the post attribution. If you use Facebook's share dialog or feed dialog the post will be attributed to your app instead of iOS.