# Can I Use [FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom] to post image to facebook via SDK 3.5?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, fbdialogs

When I use FBDialogs to post an image to facebook, facebook will show "via iOS" on the wall; How can I change "via iOS" to "via My App Name" using Facebook SDK 3.5?

```
[FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                             session:[FBSession activeSession]
                                         initialText:@"ABC"
                                              images:image
                                                urls:nil
                                             handler:^(FBOSIntegratedShareDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
                                             }];
```

Comment: posible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547616/sharing-with-ios-6-0-native-facebook-integration-posted-via-my-app-name

Comment: not dublicate, i used facebook sdk3.5

Comment: please ans this post if anyone knows ans.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of the SDK you can use `presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams` to share an image. See example below:

```
FBShareDialogPhotoParams *photoParams = [FBShareDialogPhotoParams new];
UIImage *screenshot = // Your image...
photoParams.photos = @[screenshot];
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:photoParams
                                 clientState:nil
                                     handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

                                     }];
```