# How can I post to Facebook Wall in Android without login?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, social-media

I'd like to be able to post status update to player's wall without needing to ask the player to login first.. in iOS, I'd be able to achieve via `SLComposeViewController` like shown here:

[Sharing with iOS 6.0 native Facebook integration: "Posted via my app name"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547616/sharing-with-ios-6-0-native-facebook-integration-posted-via-my-app-name)

I know it will launch a compose view controller where player can still edit the status before posting, and the result will be "Posted via iOS" instead of "Posted via My App Name", but it doesn't require app authorization since it is using the built in Accounts that is already available in iOS.

In Android, there're built in accounts in Settings as well... How do we use the account and post it like in iOS?

Comment: Use SSO for that. If Facebook app is installed and user is loged in it will not ask for credentials. If app is not installed than it will open a webview dialog for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If the Facebook app is installed, then use SSO for direct login otherwise it will open a webview asking for login details.