# Facebook mobile deep linking in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, deep-linking

I am new to mobile deep linking. I want to do deep linking while sharing post on Facebook. I followed [Facebook deep linking reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links/) but this is done using Facebook share dialog but i am using `SLComposeViewController` in my app.

To do deep linking, I followed following steps:

```
1) I have added Facebook app id in info.plist, URL Types.
2) Also in Facebook app page, 
    -- iOS Bundle ID: my bundle ID (checked it, correct) 
    -- iPhone AppStore ID: the ID (checked it, correct)
    -- iPad AppStore ID: the ID (checked it, correct)
    -- iOS SSO: Enabled 
    -- iOS Native Deep Linking: Enabled 
    -- URL Scheme Suffix: my website url
```

May i missing something?

How to do mobile deep linking with `SLComposeViewController` ?

Comment: Did you ever find a way?  As far as I can tell, you can't.  One has to use the sdk share stuff.  But I'd love to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605241/1635315). If I have shared post on Facebook using `SLComposeViewController` then on Facebook post gets displayed with 'via iOS'. Because of this my deep-linking was not happened. But When I shared my post using `SLRequest`, my post gets displayed with "via xxx" and my deep-linking is working properly.